# Why is Ubuntu server one ISO and CentOS 5 six ISOs?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos

What is the difference between Ubuntu server and CentOS that one version would require six CDs?  I have used Ubuntu and it was easy to install but I have read that CentOS was a great distribution (it didn't say why, just impressions.)

I was hoping that someone would comment on why the difference in size between the two and I hope this doesn't start some fight about somebody's favorite distro.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CentOS is based on Red Hat Enterprise Linux, which you generally buy on CD and (as Red Hat Linux) pre-dates super fast internet connections, so they ship the same number of CDs that RHEL does.  They also makes a "single server CD" up to and including 4.x, and a live CD from 5.x onwards, which you can get from the same source as the five CD ISO set.

Ubuntu Server contains the packages on the CD required to get you installed and cover most cases, and suggests you can install the rest from the network.  You can also get [DVDs of Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/downloadmirrors#dvd), but they are primarily just all the different languages all rolled into one.

Using [Jigdo](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/JigdoDownloadHowto) you could create more CDs of all the packages you want for offline use.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu server doesn't include everything, and pretty much has just enough to get you going and assumes you'll have Internet connectivity so you can download additional software with APT.

Answer (score 0):

I never installed CentOS but I bet it requires only disc#1 to install it.  CentOS provides a single CD live install disk, just like Ubuntu does.  All the remaining CDs are probably just extra stuff.  You dont need the extra stuff because it can also be downloaded by the package updater tool.

Comment: You can install Base OS from CentOS disc #1. Deselect *all* package groups when asked what you want to install. After the system is online you can yum groupinstall them. i.e. yum groupinstall "Developer Tools"

Cheers